# How to move image into folder in angular js

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I want to move image to the folder whenever user submit the form . i have tried many examples but not succeeded. i want to submit my form with image in this way:-

```
 mainApp.controller('productFormController', ['$scope', '$http', 'fileUpload', function($scope, $http, fileUpload) {
        $scope.url = 'product-submit.php?&sub=1';
        $scope.productsubmit = function(isValid) {
        if (isValid) {          

            $http.post("product_image": $scope.product_image,"product_description": $scope.product_description}).
                    success(function(data, status) {
                        console.log(data);
                    // window.location.href = 'products';
                    })



        }else{      
            $scope.errorMsg = "Form is not valid";
        }
    }           
}]);

<form class="form-horizontal" name="useradd" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type = "file" ng-model = "product_image"/>
<textarea name="product_description" class="form-control"ng-model="product_description"></textarea>
<button class="md-btn md-btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" ng-click="productsubmit(useradd.$valid)"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button> | <a href="#">Or Cancel</a>
</form>
```

I want to add my form in this way and also want to store image into folder.

Answer (score 0):

You've not set a url on your http post. Check the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) here for how to format your post.

Comment: its working fine for me, I want to store my images into folder

Comment: If your http call is indeed working then this is a problem with your php code and is not angularJs related.